# Run XBMC plugins in a .net application

Tags: .net, python, xbmc

Is there any way to use xbmc plugins in .net? im thinking about those plugins that provide access to media content like GameTrailers and stuff like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the plugin system is based on Python.  You may be able to use IronPython to run some of the plugins in XBMC, although it may not be 100% compatible.  You could also take the Python code and create a COM server object in which you could use .NET interop to interface with it.